# how to access a variable of an private inner class to oncreate() method

Tags: java, android, scope, inner-classes

here, how to print ss value from Activity's oncreate() method?

```
    MainActivity extends Activity {

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ss_View);

        //view.setText(String.valueOf(ss)); 
      }

      private class x {
        @Override
        public void func() {
         int ss = 3;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Consider some Java tutorial :) `ss` is not accessible at all since it is a local variable that only exists within the `func` method

Comment: I need the value of ss at oncreate() method for further manupulation there...........

Comment: is there any way exists.....  if I make it as global?  like...using constructor?

Comment: Why do you need a private class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make ss an instance variable of the x class and add a getter method:

```
public class InnerActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickableButtonWithBorder);

        x xInstance = new x();
        xInstance.func();
        view.setText(String.valueOf(xInstance.getSS()));

    }

    private class x {
        int ss;

        public void func() {
            ss = 3;
        }

        public Integer getSS()
        {
            return ss;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. SS variable is only created locally in your method.
Create ss variable as field of class and generate getter.
Then you can get your variable.